# Trouble installing QSTK on a MAC 10.7.5, probably because of an issue with python-dateutils and/or pandas 0.7.3

Tags: python, terminal, quantitative-finance, qstk

I am trying to install QSTK (http://wiki.quantsoftware.org/index.php?title=QSToolKit_Installation_Guide_Mac) on a Mac and am running to trouble. To make a long story short, i started with multiple versions of python on my mac (2.5, 2.6, 2.7, 3.3) and multiple modules (beautifulsoup, requests, etc). In my frustration after hours of trying to get QSTK up and running, i deleted everything python-related and tried to start over. I followed the directions on the QSTK install wiki (the link above), and when i got to step 7, which is to run this:

`python QSTK-0.2.5/Examples/Validation.py`

on the command line to see if the installation went ok, I get the following feedback from my terminal:

```
Numpy is installed and the version used is :  1.7.0
Please make sure you're using version >= 1.6.1

Matplotlib is installed and version is :  1.2.0
Please make sure you're using version >= 1.1.0

Please install python-dateutil via easy_install or some method!
Error : Please install Pandas 0.7.3
Error : Pandas can not be imported or not installed.
```

I found out I needed `python-dateutil` version `1.5` and not `2.0` (which is the latest), so i tried downgrading it, still no luck. I am very lost on what to do. Help please!

Note: I am a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 0):

*Try doing the installation with Homebrew. I assume you were using macports.*

I ran into the same issue when installing QSTK.

**uninstall macports, and install brew.**

Comment: Hey I know this is a super late response but thanks so much! That ended up working :)